# Difference between ext plugin and hook in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I read several documentation but could not get the basic difference between hook and ext plugin both are used to override the default behavior of liferay if I am not wrong. I got a link which says that ext plugin makes a new webapp/ROOT. So i could guess from this that this folder is used to override the files already provided by liferay.Hooks also provide the same functionality of overriding. So what is the main difference between them. Kindly tell a scenario where we have to use ext plugin not hook. As I am a beginner in liferay, this question seems to be very cumbersome for me. Any help would be appreciated ...so please help.

Comment: 1. Determine what modification you want to make. 2. determine if it can be done with a hook 3-6. If you don't think it can be done with a hook: Try again 7. Consider an ext. it's as close as you can get to changing the implementation itself, with separating your own code from Liferay's. But if you have a chance to go without ext: Do so. There's no guarantee for stability when you change anything there, it's typically hard to maintain. And read https://dev.liferay.com

Comment: thanks Olaf...well explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is asking about the difference and is quite narrow, while the last part (describing scenarios) would be offtopic for SO IMHO - at least more than I'd want to write in an answer. The comment seems to have helped, so I'm promoting it to an answer, explicitly without giving more scenarios.

1. Determine what modification you want to make.
2. determine if it can be done with a hook
3. If you don't think it can be done with a hook: Try again
4. If you think it can't be done with a hook: Try again
5. If you don't think it can be done with a hook: Ask someone else or try gain
6. If you still think it can't be done with a hook: try again or question the requirement
7. Consider an ext. it's as close as you can get to changing the implementation itself, with separating your own code from Liferay's.

But if you have a chance to go without ext: Do so. There's no guarantee for stability when you change anything there, it's typically hard to maintain.

And read https://dev.liferay.com